# Postgis Spring Boot Integration Testing with index based operator <->

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, postgis, spring-boot-test

I'm currently writing an integration test with spring boot and a Post**gis** connection. In my original application a query uses [the <-> operator](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html#index-based-knn). For my tests I used a h2 in-memory database with the [h2gis](http://www.h2gis.org/) extension. Unfortunately, the <-> is not recognized and throws a syntax error. Do you have any ideas how to do this with an in-memory database or is there only the chance to run a docker container with a proper postgis database running?

Thank you!

Comment: PostgreSQL (and possibly its forks) has huge number of non-standard operators not available in other DBMS. If you need them, you can only use the PostgreSQL itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it where possible to run a database similar enough to Postgres, I'd recommend against it.

We now have [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) and can therefore easily start any* database in docker container from our tests. This is preferable, because you are using the actual database you'll also see in production.

*any*: Some of the commercial variants are either huge or take a long time to start up, but Postgres works great.*